# Running Powershell Script via Chef - Invalid escape character syntax

Tags: windows, powershell, chef-infra

I have a powershell script that I'm trying to run via chef. I'm using the powershell resource. I've tried other methods of running the script but due to the machines strict access controls I can only use the Chef powershell resource.

I think the run is failing due to this specific line in the script:

```
$FileServerSharePath ='\\files.myshare.com\Public\SOFTWARE\mysoftware\LatestInstaller'
```

The specific error is: `Invalid escape character syntax`

This is an example of what my recipe looks like:

```
powershell_script 'install-stuff' do
  code <<-EOH
    code stuff blah blah blah
  EOH
end
```

I've tried to escape the double backslashes but still get the error. I'm not sure what else I can try to get past this error. I'm not a windows person so thank you for any help.

Update:
I think it may be a specific issue with my server config.

Comment: Running that line in a regular powershell window does not cause an error - I would try to determine the exact line causing the error by running similar code in an unmanaged computer.  If that line causes the error, it is caused by chef and not by powershell.

Comment: @LeeExothermix running the script directly in Windows doesn't produce any errors and it runs with no issue. So, I tried just copying the script over and using the execute resource to run the script but ran into access control errors.

Comment: Can you add some of your chef resource definition? Chef requires \ to be escaped in text it's processing, so UNC paths end up looking like `'\\\\server\\share\\file'`. Are you calling the script file from powershell, or are you feeding the script content into powershell as a command?

Comment: Using the Powershell command exactly as in your question within the `code` block didn't produce any errors for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tested a lot of different ways of getting past the error. It seems that Chef didn't like any backslashes in the Powershell script resource. I switched all of the backslashes to forward slashes in the script. I got a different error after that. I decided to just move my msi to the machine with chef then use the windows_packages resource to install the msi.

This is what worked:

```
powershell_script 'download_installer' do
  code <<-EOH
  $user_agent = '123456789useragent'
  $source = 'http://blah.mybucket.net.s3.amazonaws.com/path1/path2/installer_12345.msi'
  $destination = 'c:/Windows/Temp/installer_12345.msi'
  Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $source -OutFile $destination -UserAgent $user_agent
  EOH
end

windows_package "install_software" do
  installer_type :msi
  action :install
  source "c:/Windows/Temp/installer_12345.msi"
  options '/q VAR1=123456789 VAR2=abcdefgh VAR3=blah'
end
```